# Postfix sends plain text emails from PHP but rejects html

Tags: php, email, postfix, sendmail

After moving to another host my site stopped sending E-mails (UTF-8 HTML). But I'm still able to send text emails like these:

```
echo test | mail -t me@example.com -s test

php -r 'mail("me@example.com", "test", "test")'
```

Where should I look for details of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Digging in `/var/spool/mail` made it clear with bounce message:

```
SMTPUTF8 is required, but was not offered by host mxs.mail.ru [94.100.180.31]
```

So I've had to add the line `smtputf8_enable = no` to the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` to make HTML e-mails go